# C++ one argument boolean constructor and "new" keyword: Logic Error

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments

I have the following class in c++

```
class MyClass {

public:
  bool flag;

  MyClass (bool flag = false) {
    this->flag = flag;
  }
...
};
```

In my main (used for testing) I have something like so

```
int main() {
 MyClass number1 = MyClass(true);
 MyClass number2 = MyClass(false);
 MyClass number3 = new MyClass(false);
 MyClass number4 = new MyClass(true);
 MyClass number5 = new MyClass();
 std::cout << number1.flag << number2.flag << std::endl;
 std::cout << number3.flag << number4. flag << number5.flag << std::endl;
}
```

And my output (imagine boolean outputs true or false and the output is formatted better)

```
true, false 
true, true, true
```

The problem is when I use the "new" keyword to make a "MyClass" object it will always set the flag variable to true regardless of what I do or don't put into the argument constructor.

It works for the constructors not using "new" but not the ones using it. The only real difference I know between using and not using the keyword new is that if you don't use it, the variable is created on the stack, otherwise it is created on the heap. I don't see any way this could keep coming up wrong.

What would need to change if I wanted it to work properly?
I do have other methods in the class that can successfully modify the flag variable, but initializing it doesn't work. I also tried using the member initialization list to construct the variable but that doesn't work either.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Here is the code that does compile. I have two files, Test.c++ and AbstractCell.h. AbstractCell is MyClass and when this code runs it outputs "isAlive: 1"

```
 void test_abstract_2(){
   AbstractCell one = new AbstractCell();

      std::cout << std::endl <<  "isAlive:  " << one.alive << std::endl;

  }
```

Comment: That code shouldn't compile. `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: you never ran that code, it doesn't compile at all!

Comment: Compiles fine for me, short for includes and `return 0;`. there is no reason why it should not compile in its current form.

Comment: . . . well it does compile . . . so ya . . . and I ran it . . . that's how I know the output is wrong . . . yyaaaaaaaaa

Comment: **Aside**: Prefer using initialization lists in your constructor when possible, like this: `MyClass (bool flag = false) : flag(flag) { }`

Comment: Do you prefer initialization lists or are there reasons that it should be used? To my understanding, they are required in some cases, but, in a case like this, it doesn't matter what is used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The pointer returned by `new` gets implicitly converted to `bool`, which is then passed to `MyClass(bool)`.**

In other words, the following:

```
MyClass number3 = new MyClass(false);
```

is equivalent to:

```
MyClass number3(bool(new MyClass(false)));
```

Since the pointer returned by `new` is never null, the conversion always yields `true`, which is what gets passed to `number3`'s constructor. The newly allocated pointer gets leaked.

You probably meant to say:

```
 MyClass* number3 = new MyClass(false);
 MyClass* number4 = new MyClass(true);
 MyClass* number5 = new MyClass();
```

(note the asterisks.)

You would not have had this problem if you declared the constructor `explicit`:

```
  explicit MyClass (bool flag = false) {
    this->flag = flag;
  }
```

The code would fail to compile, which would immediate tell you that something was amiss.

Comment: I could be wrong, but wouldn't that involve 3 implicit conversions though (which isn't allowed IIRC)?

Comment: Ah ha! I am an idiot. This works. It does compile though. I do use the following to compile it though . . . (also using valgrind)

g++ -pedantic -std=c++0x -lcppunit -ldl -Wall TestLife.c++ -o TestLife.c++.app

Comment: @Pubby It's just one implicit conversion, from pointer to bool.

Comment: @user1348913: Add the following flags: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems there:

The first one is that `new` returns a pointer, not a static object. You normally use it like this:

```
MyClass* number3 = new MyClass(false);
std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<number3->flag<<std::endl;  //outputs 'false'
...  //do more stuff with number3
delete number3;
```

The second problem is that the code compiles as written.
Edited: I thought that the code shouldn't normally compile as written, but I think I was wrong. Too many things are implicitly convertible to bool in C++, it seems.

So I'll revise that and say the second problem is the code leaks memory by constructing anonymous temporary dynamic objects which don't get destroyed :)

Comment: Thank you. I tested something similar but of course I didn't have a constructor that takes bool.